# Spring XML - autowired Logger doesn't determine target class name

Tags: java, xml, spring, logging

I've added `log4j` Logger into Spring xml configuration to use it later as a component:

```
<bean id="logger" class="org.apache.log4j.Logger" factory-method="getLogger">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="LoggerName"/>
</bean>
```

seems everything works fine, but logs are don't point to the target classes where they're have been autowired:

```
2016-06-30 09:54:23 DEBUG LoggerName:29 - Account does not exists
```

How to setup the Logger bean properly to let it determine the target class names like this:

```
2016-06-30 09:54:23 DEBUG AccountValidator:29 - Account does not exists
```

where `AccountValidator` is actual class that the Logger has been autowired into?

Comment: Why do you want to inject it ? Did you try to instanciate it with the lhe class you want to use. e.g. private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AccountValidator.class);

Comment: @tbetous, yeah it would work. Dunno, maybe it's about code design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you should instanciate a logger per class :

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AccountValidator.class);
```

If you absolutely need to do it with injection you can use CDI's injection point mechanism. This post is about what you want :

[What is the Spring DI equivalent of CDI's InjectionPoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685316/what-is-the-spring-di-equivalent-of-cdis-injectionpoint)